# How to clear memory stream

Tags: c#, wcf, image, memorystream, data-conversion

I use this code to covert image from binary to image.

```
public class ImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var memStream = new MemoryStream(((MeetPoint_B2C.ServiceReference1.Binary)value).Bytes);
        memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        var empImage = new BitmapImage();
        empImage.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None;
        empImage.SetSource(memStream);
        return empImage;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I had error when loading more than 20 image from my database.
It is Exception was unhandled. The request is not supported.
I think is memory stream full already. So how can I reset the memory stream? I know can be using `dispose()` or `memorystream.setLength` to `0` but how to or where should I put the coding?

The exception detail

```
System.OutOfMemoryException was unhandled
  Message=OutOfMemoryException
  StackTrace:
       at MS.Internal.FrameworkCallbacks.NotifyManagedDebuggerOnNativeOOM()
       at MS.Internal.XcpImports.BitmapSource_SetSourceNative(IntPtr bitmapSource, CValue& byteStream)
       at MS.Internal.XcpImports.BitmapSource_SetSource(BitmapSource bitmapSource, CValue& byteStream)
       at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource.SetSourceInternal(Stream streamSource)
       at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage.SetSourceInternal(Stream streamSource)
       at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource.SetSource(Stream streamSource)
       at MeetPoint_B2C.ImageConverter.Convert(Object value, Type targetType, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
       at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.ConvertToTarget(Object value)
       at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.GetValue(DependencyObject d, DependencyProperty dp)
       at System.Windows.DependencyObject.EvaluateExpression(DependencyProperty property, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry)
       at System.Windows.DependencyObject.EvaluateBaseValue(DependencyProperty property, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, ValueOperation operation)
       at System.Windows.DependencyObject.EvaluateEffectiveValue(DependencyProperty property, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry newEntry, ValueOperation operation)
       at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(DependencyProperty property, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, ValueOperation operation)
       at System.Windows.DependencyObject.RefreshExpression(DependencyProperty dp)
       at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.RefreshExpression()
       at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.SendDataToTarget()
       at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.SourceAcquired()
       at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.System.Windows.IDataContextChangedListener.OnDataContextChanged(Object sender, DataContextChangedEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.DataContextChanged(Object sender, DataContextChangedEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnDataContextChanged(DataContextChangedEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnAncestorDataContextChanged(DataContextChangedEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.NotifyDataContextChanged(DataContextChangedEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnAncestorDataContextChanged(DataContextChangedEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.NotifyDataContextChanged(DataContextChangedEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnTreeParentUpdated(DependencyObject newParent, Boolean bIsNewParentAlive)
       at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateTreeParent(IManagedPeer oldParent, IManagedPeer newParent, Boolean bIsNewParentAlive, Boolean keepReferenceToParent)
       at MS.Internal.FrameworkCallbacks.ManagedPeerTreeUpdate(IntPtr oldParentElement, IntPtr parentElement, IntPtr childElement, Byte bIsParentAlive, Byte bKeepReferenceToParent, Byte bCanCreateParent)
       at MS.Internal.XcpImports.Measure_WithDesiredSizeNative(IntPtr element, Single inWidth, Single inHeight, Single& outWidth, Single& outHeight)
       at MS.Internal.XcpImports.UIElement_Measure_WithDesiredSize(UIElement element, Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure_WithDesiredSize(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureChild(UIElement child, Size layoutSlotSize)
       at System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(IntPtr nativeTarget, Double inWidth, Double inHeight, Double& outWidth, Double& outHeight)
       at MS.Internal.XcpImports.MeasureOverrideNative(IntPtr element, Single inWidth, Single inHeight, Single& outWidth, Single& outHeight)
       at MS.Internal.XcpImports.FrameworkElement_MeasureOverride(FrameworkElement element, Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(IntPtr nativeTarget, Double inWidth, Double inHeight, Double& outWidth, Double& outHeight)
```

This is used by the following `.xaml`

```
<Grid.Resources>
   <src:ImageConverter x:Key="imgConverter"/>
</Grid.Resources>
<Image Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Height="136" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    Margin="16,16,0,0" Name="imgEmp" Stretch="Fill"
    VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200"
    Source="{Binding Image, Converter={StaticResource imgConverter}}"/>
```

Comment: Are you sure it is failing because of the number of calls and not on a specific image?

Comment: You are using different memory stream each time so you don't need to reset anything. The exception is due to something else, try to wrap the code inside convert in an exception handler and report the precise exception.

Comment: It's not clear exactly what the context is - if this is a WCF *server*, it's relatively unusual to be using WPF classes...

Comment: @user1504015 - The code you provided does not appear to be the reason for the expection.  It appears the exception is caused by `MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult` although its not until several calls later that `System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource.SetSource` even shows up.  There is something else going on here.

Comment: @user1504015 - Post the code that calls this method.  Your problem exists there.

Comment: **The code you posted isn't the calling method.** It is just the XAML code for an event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `BitmapImage` object takes ownership of the stream, you won't be able to close (or dispose of) it properly, so I recommend something along the lines of:

```
public BitmapImage Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) 
{ 
    var empImage = new BitmapImage(); 
    empImage.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None; 
    empImage.SetSource(new MemoryStream(((MeetPoint_B2C.ServiceReference1.Binary)value).Bytes); ); 
    return empImage; 
}
```

In the calling method, implement your own resource cleanup.  BitmapImage does not implement IDisposable, so a using statement can't be used.  Microsoft should consider implementing IDisposable when it clearly contains references to unmanaged resources:

```
public void ConvertBitmap()
{
    BitmapImage img = null;
    try
    {
        img = Convert(// pass in your params);

        // do stuff with your img
    }
    finally
    {
        // dispose of the memorystream in case of exception
        if(img != null && img.StreamSource != null) img.StreamSource.Dispose();
    }
}
```

This will ensure that the original `MemoryStream` is cleaned up properly even in the case of an exception.

Answer (score 2):

You're already creating a new `MemoryStream` each time you get asked to convert - although you shouldn't need to seek in this case. You don't need to reset anything.

You should really find out *exactly* what exception is being thrown - it may be *nothing* to do with being out of memory. You've edited the question to show the stack trace, but not the type of exception being thrown. One possibility is that it's something to do with using WPF controls in a WCF service, if your question tags are anything to go by.

EDIT: Note that even though you don't want to dispose of the `MemoryStream`, you *should* make sure you dispose of the `BitmapImage` result when you're done with it. Unfortunately we don't have enough context about what you're doing to give any advice on that front.

Comment: but there are 1 time i am going to convert many image so it had thrown me this error.

Comment: @user1504015: Sorry, I don't understand what you're saying. Please rephrase it.

Comment: The coding is running well when i load about 20 image..but it occur the error as above when it > 20 image.

Comment: @user1504015 - You need to post the entire exception including what type of exception happen.  Without this information is unlikely we can help you.